# What is which in Perl?

Tags: perl

When I run

```
perl -e 'which("clang")'
```

in Windows Command Prompt I get an empty line, but on Linux I get:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::which called at -e line 1.
```

I am asking because I am trying to figure out why `which` does not work in OpenSSL build script:

```
# see if there is NDK clang on $PATH, "universal" or "standalone"
if (which("clang") =~ m|^$ndk/.*/prebuilt/([^/]+)/|) { ... }
```

where the condition is always false even if `clang` is in the PATH.

Comment: Single quotes are not a special character in Windows cmd. So basically you executed the perl statement `'which(...)'` and not `which(...)` (note the quotes) - i.e. you executed a constant string and thus got an empty line.

Comment: Re "*What is which in Perl?*", Perl does not have a `which` builtin. /// Re "*I am trying to figure out why which does not work*", "Does not work" is not an adequate description of the problem. You have not provided enough information for us to answer your question. What problem are you facing? What behviour do you get? What behaviour do you want? What is this `which` sub you're asking about?

Comment: See also [Win32::App::which](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::App::which) and [PerlPowerTools](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlPowerTools)

Comment: @ikegami Looks like the condition is false because the path is in 8.3 format, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74099526/how-to-disable-ms-dos-8-3-filenames-in-perl

Comment: See also  https://linux.die.net/man/1/which

Answer (score 1):

`which` is not a Perl builtin function.

```
% perl -we 'print which("clang")'
Undefined subroutine &main::which called at -e line 1.
```

Keep in mind the Windows command line does not use the same quoting rules as the Linux command line, unless you're using something like WSL or bash for Windows.

The subroutine `which` is defined at https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/Configure#L3264 (or a similar line in other versions of the code). You'll need to make sure you've got all the build dependencies installed, all the application paths and library/include paths configured correctly, that you're following the installation directions accurately, and that you're doing things in the proper order.

You'll especially want to look in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/af33b200da8040c78dbfd8405878190980727171/NOTES-WINDOWS.md and https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-PERL.md to make sure you're following the OpenSSL project's recommendations for their build system on Windows if native Windows is where you intend to do the builds.