# How to disable MS-DOS 8.3 filenames in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to run some script in Windows Command Prompt that fails at the following line:

```
# see if there is NDK clang on $PATH, "universal" or "standalone"
if (which("clang") =~ m|^$ndk/.*/prebuilt/([^/]+)/|) { ... }
```

because `which("clang")` is in 8.3 format: `C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\231~1.777\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.EXE`

For example, if I add the following into that script:

```
print("$ndk\n");
print(which("clang"));
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944
C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\201~1.594\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.EXE
```

This is executed as part of openssl's installation. It defines `which` as follows:

```perl
sub which
{
    my ($name)=@_;

    if (eval { require IPC::Cmd; 1; }) {
        IPC::Cmd->import();
        return scalar IPC::Cmd::can_run($name);
    } else {
        # if there is $directories component in splitpath,
        # then it's not something to test with $PATH...
        return $name if (File::Spec->splitpath($name))[1];

        foreach (File::Spec->path()) {
            my $fullpath = catfile($_, "$name$target{exe_extension}");
            if (-f $fullpath and -x $fullpath) {
                return $fullpath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For PATH, I have the following:

```
PATH=
   C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin;
   C:\dev\PFiles\Strawberry\perl\bin;
   C:\Python310\Scripts\;
   C:\Python310\;
   C:\WINDOWS\system32;
   C:\WINDOWS;
   C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
   C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
   C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
   C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
   C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
   C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
   C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

Comment: @RaymondChen there are full names in my PATH

Comment: `m||` is testing for forward-slash but `which` appears to be returning backslashes

Comment: I'm looking at [Win32::App::which](https://metacpan.org/dist/Win32-App-which), and it honors the long paths in the `PATH`. I don't know what `$ndk` is. What is `$ENV{PATH}`?

Comment: @RaymondChen `$ndk` is `C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944`  How to print `$ENV{PATH}`? `print("$ENV{PATH}")` - does not work.

Comment: Works for me. Also can simplify to just `print $ENV{PATH}`. The question is a little confusing because you say "run some script in Windows Command Prompt" but then your code is a perl script, not a batch file. Can you include a full self-contained perl script, including the `require`/`use` statement, plus details on what flavor/version of perl you're using. I'm using ActiveState Perl v5.14.1.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, `print $ENV{PATH};` displays something strange: `C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\201~1.594\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.EXEC:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin; ... `

Comment: @RaymondChen by my `PATH` variable in Windows Command Prompt contains long paths (see the post). I use Strawberry perl v5.28.0

Comment: @RaymondChen the full source code of the script: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/Configurations/15-android.conf

Comment: Re "*How to disable MS-DOS 8.3 filenames in Perl?*", None of Perl's builtins return 8.3 file names. As I said in your previous question, we can't answer your questions unless you tell us what is this `which` about which you're talking.

Comment: Please provide the output of this command: `perl -v | find "This is" & echo %PATH% | perl -nE"say '--'; say for grep /\bndk\b/, split /;/" & perl -E"say '--'; say for grep /\bndk\b/, split /;/, $ENV{PATH}"`

Comment: @ikegami The output is `--
C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
--
C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\20.1.5948944\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin`

Comment: @ikegami yes, I added `print $ENV{PATH};` before line 105 of this script https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/Configurations/15-android.conf

Comment: @ikegami the output is `ok`

Comment: @ikegami yes it is probably a bug in the script

Comment: ug, I must be tired? Deleted the last few comments cause they were all wrong.

Comment: Yikes, the `which` function is [a custom function in that repo](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/9b25f52a4425d03fee1364d3531331d5d37ef742/Configure#L3255). You get to debug that custom function. (From the `print $ENV{PATH}`, it looks like somebody converted the PATH to 8.3 already.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have IPC::Cmd installed, `which` uses it. That module returns 8.3 names for some reason.

```
>perl -E"say for grep /\bPuTTY\b/, split /;/, $ENV{PATH}"
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\

>perl -MIPC::Cmd -E"say IPC::Cmd::can_run('putty')"
C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY\putty.EXE
```

You can work around the issue by removing the attempt to use IPC::Cmd.

```perl
sub which
{
    my ($name)=@_;

#    if (eval { require IPC::Cmd; 1; }) {
#        IPC::Cmd->import();
#        return scalar IPC::Cmd::can_run($name);
#    } else {
        # if there is $directories component in splitpath,
        # then it's not something to test with $PATH...
        return $name if (File::Spec->splitpath($name))[1];

        foreach (File::Spec->path()) {
            my $fullpath = catfile($_, "$name$target{exe_extension}");
            if (-f $fullpath and -x $fullpath) {
                return $fullpath;
            }
        }
#    }
}
```

`which` is found in `Configure`.